# Can this circuit be simplified?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, filter, single-supply-op-amp

The circuit is a LPF with a buffer stage in front of it that uses a linear pot. to control gain & attenuation. The setup is such that the response of the linear pot. is similar to a log. pot..

A single 5V power supply is a known limitation, however the design must have this.

The 1st stage gets input from a CD player (low Z output), this goes to the buffer with DC offset added. This goes to a 2nd stage which sets the potential gain that can be set by the pot. by the ratio of R6/R5. Next, the LPF.

The circuit uses 3 op-amps and 2 levels of DC offset are added. If the circuit could be simplified it would be great. Thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTFZsm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>